# Type where object cannot have property

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering if it's possible in TypeScript to provide some sort of intersection type that requires a type to *not have* a specific property. For my example, I have a bunch of models from the database.

```
type User = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  email: string,
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date,
  password: string
}
```

What I want is a way to define some `ResultWithoutSensitiveData<T>` type, which says "User CANNOT have created_at, updated_at, and password". Something that is basically `Omit` or `Pick` with keys instead of types. I've tried some form of conditional infer resulting in `never`, but I end up with compiler complaints about how undefined can't be assigned to type never. I just can't get it quite right.

I want the compiler and IDE to tell devs if they haven't removed sensitive properties.

Comment: if you want to be sure to NOT have such a fields, then you should filter the live object (not just the type!). I don't know any other way to achieve that goal.

Comment: Of course, I'm not expecting typescript to do any type mapping for me. That information isn't available at run time. I'm just trying to write code that is less likely to inadvertently expose sensitive data.

Comment: Also, what was the purpose of someone editing my post? I get modifying the title a bit, but they removed a whole sentence that basically edits out my communication personality. Is this just badge chasing? StackOverflow is wild in 2023.

Comment: The deleted sentence did not add anything to the post.

Comment: I'm not saying it did, but it also did not take away anything or make it harder to understand. I guess I just didn't realize that stack overflow had become a place where I had to have some formality when asking a question and couldn't discuss a problem I was having with the same level of informality I would have with my coworkers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine `Omit` and `never`:

```
type SensitiveKeys = 'created_at' | 'updated_at' | 'password';
type ResultWithoutSensitiveData<T> = Omit<T, SensitiveKeys> & {
  [key in SensitiveKeys]?: never; // the question mark is to make the keys optional to type T
};
```

You can have a look at the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5&ssl=12&ssc=35&pln=12&pc=94#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKClAlgEwC4oA7AVwFsAjJAbm1IEMKJi5hFcSBzenCCo1wAbNhy68GAY0QRGwCPgD684gBF5EPlDJh8m5aqgaF2sIzhwA7gHtERKO0496AX3qZQkKAGUIJOFxgXAA3CABpCBA4VCgAchk5BUNgOKgAH3jdfWSVVIz480tbezj6L2gAJQg4MmFgAHUggAsbMmA-AKDQiBNGAB4AFQA+WIB5CiChgBpff0DgsMjo0YAyDAYAbQBrKLwSOa7FiKi4AF0AfmISCDDEWigAekeoYGboAEcyGuCbA8FENs8DFgDYoIJdq93lBdtEoDYwL8SIxhK8wRUoINMO5MJgpH92DoEIhiPAkLEsDgCMQAIzTBjIljEOKMfCTEhxen8QQiZms9kAAXYjCk2xsdwAZsIbFYAHT4iic6SyAx5a4QKzGTQACgAlFydHpVUYbpqTBA9QaitY7A44jSAEwAZgALABWABsSpxmGemOauBicFadXwUBoUDG4TxBOAUFktXqNOI1UTjRabQ6826YT6-TJiFGaEpeAcZGJsoIBsZrCJSFlNYNAiEojriFlzZE9J9fsG4GgcQLaUDpBscYsgW4yKowmgoNe-fiqbq6bemc6Cx6eYLwziMYCcYTK4dKZqK6aa-aG5zvXkAx3sXLdCgmCAA).

Comment: Thanks! I chose this answer because it's a new type rather than leaving the properties on as optional, which isn't what I'm intending.

Comment: `Partial<Record<SensitiveKeys, never>>` would also work

Answer (score 0):

You need `optional never`.
Depending on your `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` config they may look like `password?: never` or `password?: undefined` (as TS adds `| undefined` to all optional properties if `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` is off)

Hovewer, note that you can assign value of type `let x: {a: 1, password: 1}` to `let y: {a: 1}`, which you can assign to `let z: {a: 1, password?: never}`, so a runtime check may be better
Generally, having validators for all the inputs and outputs of your server is recommented

```
type CleanUser = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  email: string,
  created_at?: never,
  updated_at?: never,
  password?: never,
}
type User = {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    email: string,
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date,
    password: string
}
type sensitiveKey = 'created_at' | 'updated_at' | 'password'

type Pure<T> = T extends infer R ? {[K in keyof R]: T[K]} : T;

type ResultWithoutSensitiveData<T> = Pure<Omit<T, sensitiveKey> & Partial<Record<Extract<keyof T, sensitiveKey>, never>>>

type User1 = ResultWithoutSensitiveData<User>
//   ^?
// type User1 = {
//     id: number;
//     name: string;
//     email: string;
//     created_at?: undefined;
//     updated_at?: undefined;
//     password?: undefined;
// }
```

```
import { type } from "arktype"

const CleanUser = type(
    {
        id: "number",
        name: "string",
        email: "email"
    },
    { keys: "strict" }
)

CleanUser.assert({
    id: 123,
    name: "asd",
    email: "a@b.com",
    password: "blah"
})
// ^! runtime error
// ParseError: password must be removed
```

Comment: My main argument against this specific answer is that I don't want the properties left on the type. I want to treat it as a new type and for my code to not have optional chaining parameters where not needed.

Comment: Some sort of runtime check for all unsafe keys coming from an API method is probably a good idea. Though my main goal here is to have users working with my code get in the habit of using these "clean" return types, to make sure they're mutating results properly using destructuring. Then I have the benefit of forcing them to write better code the first time, rather than needing to catch it at review.